# Problems keeping Git history after migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, git, android-studio

I want to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio. The import works fine, but the file structure is different after import.
I followed the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24741965/2489037%20this) thread, and copied the .git directory in the root of the newly imported Android-Studio project. But git does not seem to recognize my "moved" source files but lists them as deleted and also as new files.

Old structure:

```
MyApp
|--src
    |--com.myapp
```

New structure:

```
NewApp
|--_myApp
    |--src
       |--main
          |--java
             |--com.myapp
```

Is there any I can tell git to find my files without manually doing it?

Comment: did you try a simple `git add -u` at the root directory? blobs should be recognized since they haven't changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you,  Sebastien Dawans, this was indeed the missing link. After adding with git add -u, git recognized some of my files as renamed. I wonder why not all files. Android Studio seems to touch some files while importing, which causes git to have problems identifying them. So I copied the `com.myapp` folder containing the java files from my eclipse folders to Android Studio folder replacing the imported files. Same with the `res` directory. Than git add . and git add -u

That seems to fix the issue.

Comment: I needed first to use git mv on my original repository in order to update the folders hierarchy commit, and then copied the .git to the migration folder and all worked.